# Kubernetes hostPath with directoryOrCreate not working

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to create a simple pod that is using `hostPath` for volumes.
The settings are quite straightforward:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test
          ...
          volumeMounts:
          - name: mntdatas3fs
            mountPath: /var/s3:shared
            ...
      volumes:
      - name: devfuse
        hostPath:
          path: /dev/fuse
      - name: mntdatas3fs
        hostPath:
          path: "/mnt/s3bucket/my_backet"
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

On the first run - everything is working properly, the directory gets created as it should.
But if I will delete this pod and re-create it, it will fail to run with the following error:
`Error: failed to start container "storage-mount": Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/mnt/s3bucket/my_backet': mkdir /mnt/s3bucket/my_backet: file exists`

Comment: In general, `hostPath:` volumes can cause a lot of consistency problems, since you're not guaranteed that a pod will run on a specific node, or in your case that only one pod will be trying to mount something on that host path.  I'd try to stick to Kubernetes's native volume management; do not mount `hostPath:` volumes and especially do not try to use systems like FUSE to mount additional content from inside the container.

Comment: I do understand this concern, typically, I wouldn't go for that.
In this specific scenario, I need to mount S3 to a container as a filesystem, this is why I'm using `FUSE` here, something that is based on this https://gardener.cloud/documentation/tutorials/s3/